# What is the most universal way to get metadata about defined endpoint parameters?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, minimal-apis

We can define that some of the endpoint parameters should be bound from query string: `[FromQuery(Name= "someParamName")]`.

Is this mapping information stored anywhere in endpoint metadata?

**I want to ensure that passed query string parameter is defined for the endpoint.**

```
[HttpGet("foo")]
public IActionResult Foo([FromQuery("foo-param")]string param)
{
    ...
} 

[HttpGet("bar")]
public IActionResult Bar()
{
    ...
}
```

Here `/foo?foo-param=something` is fine, because `foo-param` is an expected one,
but for `/bar?foo-param=something` url `foo-param` is foreign.

For controller endpoints I could locate `ControllerActionDescriptor` metadata entry, which has `Parameters` collection with `BindingInfo` containing all the data I need.

However, for mapped endpoints I get only request delegate information.

Sure, I could get `ParameterInfo` objects from delegate's `Target` method, and then check for `[FromQuery]` attribute, and so on, but it's quite a lot of low-level boilerplate code.
I also see that EndpointsApiExplorer extacts this information and swagger generated correct documentation. Thus I assume there sohuld be a universal way to get the information about endpoint's parameters.